# Kendo MVVM data binding with a custom Kendo widget

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I created a custom Kendo widget that is will be a composite control made up of a few other widgets. I have everything working except MVVM-enabling it, specifically I can't get the view model's value to update whenever the control is updated. However, if I update the view model directly, the control's value get's updated, just not the other way around. It needs to be two-way.  I put together an example of this issue:

http://jsbin.com/obejey/3/

Any help would be hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You are SO close! :) All you are missing is to trigger a `change` event when your value changes. To do this, simply monitor the `change` event of your `ComboBox` and when it changes, trigger a `change` of your custom widget.

Add this bit of code:

```
    _initAutoComplete: function () {
        var that = this;
        that.select.kendoComboBox({

          ...,

          // ADDED CODE...
          change: function () {
            that.trigger("change", {field: "value"});
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: on a side note, I've been meaning to write up a blog post on this exact topic; doing a deep-dive into how to do MVVM bindings for custom widgets and how the Kendo MVVM binders work with widgets. I've just been too lazy to do the write up... :)